# Problem while running a Jar file in ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu-18.04, blazegraph

I am not very familiar with the Ubuntu. I have moved a jar file relatd to  Blazegraph which I used on my Windows machine to my Ubuntu VM (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Bionic).

I have also used `chmod +x filename` to make it executable. But when running the file, I get the following error:

> ERROR: Banner.java:160: Uncaught exception in thread
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.bigdata.rdf.sail.webapp.StandaloneNanoSparqlServer.main(StandaloneNanoSparqlServer.java:142)

Why do I get this message? I also found [this thread](https://github.com/blazegraph/database/issues/89) on GitHub, but seems no one had a chance in fixing it!

Note: The file is blazegraph.jar which acts as a local server for the blazegraph so I can run SPARQL queries on some ontologies. Is this because the file is trying to act as a server and possibly firewall issues? However, the server will be at `http://localhost:9999/blazegraph/` which I think shouldn't have to do anything with the firewall (if there is any on Linux).

Comment: Well, usually when there's an open bug on the project's issue tracker... there's an actual open bug. Especially if you tried the suggested workarounds and they didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this is a bug with the Blazegraph.

See these links to read more about the problem: [[1]](https://sourceforge.net/p/bigdata/discussion/676946/thread/74643593/) [[2]](https://sourceforge.net/p/bigdata/discussion/676946/thread/771a036f/).

PS: There have been some ways for getting rid of the problem but they did not work for me or I could't make them work. I initially wanted to remove this question but thought maybe others have the same problem.